# Eclipse Projects are gone

Tags: java, eclipse

My original computer with eclipse had crashed. I had backed up my entire hard drive. When I went and ran eclipse all my projects were gone. Is there a way to recover these projects.

Comment: Import your workspace directory.

Comment: ya, agreed.  If you backed up the OC you should be fine

Comment: okay I am running windows 7 is this under my docs

Comment: Depends on where you put it. If you remember the name of the workspace, search for it.

Comment: I used default values when it was installed

Answer (score 2):

If the projects are still on your hard drive, but not appearing in the Eclipse IDE, then:

1) In Eclipse, **File>Switch Workspace** to your prior workspace directory.

2) If that doesn't help, import your projects into the workspace with **File>Import**, using as an import source **General>Existing Projects into Workspace**. A dialog will appear asking for a directory in which to search for Eclipse projects. Pick one, and pick the projects to import.

If necessary, repeat step 2 for multiple parent directories.

Alternatively, if you or a teammate has created a "Team Project Set" beforehand, you can import it with **File>Import** using **Team>Team Project Set**.

Comment: okay got it thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. And welcome to stackoverflow. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). And also see ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Import your Workspace-Directory from Backup